# GPIB simulator (alternative to PyVISA-sim)

Tags: windows, python-3.x, virtual-machine, gpib, pyvisa

While coding, it is not always easy to have a connected instrument via GPIB.
Python offers the possibility to simulate an instrument using PyVISA-sim.

Unless I am mistaken, the community is not really active, and I got several errors:

1- PyVISA-sim gives a large panel of "virtual" instruments, but only one can effectively communicate with my code

2- While creating my own .ymal file, python fails to recognize it

I was wondering if there is an alternate way?

I will be more greedy: is there a GPIB simulator that can also simulate an instrument response?

For example: while simulating a voltmeter, the virtual instrument will effectively return me some "random" readings.

The goal is to check if my Byte to Single converter is working properly

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that it's very much a DIY job. There are hardware instrument simulators but I'm not sure this will help you with your byte converter.

Instrument Simulator:
http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/10763

Does the user manual not give you the format for the returned data?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I could wrap my head around the conversion problem I had, but to do so I needed to be near my instrument for 3 days in a raw
I have seen that NI simulator instrument...a bit costly for me ^_^! 
It is unfortunate that such solution doesn't exist yet (and i am not a programming expert to do it myself u_u)
I realized that PyVisa-sim doesn't exist on Spyder, or am I wrong?